# Double Diophantine approximation

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity, computational-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $0 < \alpha < 1$. For any $n$ there is a closest lower Diophantine approximation $\max p / q \leq \alpha$ with integer $0 \leq p < q \leq n$. It can be found efficiently, e.g., with Stern-Brocot tree in $O(\log^2 n)$, assuming there is a constant-time oracle comparing any rational with $\alpha$. It is known that the best approximation satisfies $\alpha - p / q = O(n^{-2})$.

Let's introduce *lower double Diophantine approximation* $D_n(\alpha)$ as $\max p_1 / q_1 \cdot p_2 / q_2 \leq \alpha$ with integer $0 \leq p_i < q_i \leq n$ for $i = 1, 2$.

**Q1.** How fast can one find best lower double Diophantine approximation (assuming the constant-time comparison oracle)? Trivial solution is to sort all rationals $p / q$ with $p < q \leq n$ and use two-pointers search for $O(n^2 \log n)$ complexity. Can we do $o(n^2)$? $o(n)$?

**Q2.** Let $\Delta(\alpha, n)$ be $\alpha - D_n(\alpha)$. One can look for a bound $\Delta(\alpha, n) = O(n^{-c})$ uniform for all $\alpha$. A natural guess that $c = 4$ is sharp. Is it true, and how can one prove this?

Note that for a fixed $n$ we have $\max_{\alpha} \Delta(\alpha, n) = \Omega(n^{-2})$, attained at $\alpha = 1/n^2 - \varepsilon$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\alpha=1/n^2-\epsilon$? Surely $\alpha$ has to be a constant independent of $n$?

Comment: Ah, there are two different bounds we can speak of, I didn't clarify that enough.